# The usage of pointer star in C

Tags: c, pointers

I asked the question: [Pass array by reference using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438625/pass-array-by-reference-using-c). I realized my problem was the usage of the pointer star in C. And eventually it turned out that, this method works fine for my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FillArray(int** myArray)
{   
     *myArray = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

     (*myArray)[0] = 1;
     (*myArray)[1] = 2;
}

int main()
{
     int* myArray = NULL;
     FillArray(& myArray);  
     printf("%d", myArray[0]);
     return 0;
}
```

Everyting was fine up to that point. Then, I modified the *FillArray()* function like the following for a better code readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FillArray(int** myArray)
{
     int* temp = (*myArray);

     temp = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
     temp[0] = 1;
     temp[1] = 2;
}

int main()
{
     int* myArray = NULL;
     FillArray(& myArray);  
     printf("%d", myArray[0]);
     return 0;
}
```

Now, I get the following run-time error at the printf line:

> Unhandled exception at 0x773115de in Trial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Even though I'm not an C expert, it seemed legitimate to do this modifying. However, apparently it doesn't work. Isn't the syntax a little bit confusing? Do I miss something here?

Thanks for your helpful answers,

Sait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`temp` gets a copy of the address of `myArray`, but then you assign some `malloc`ed memory to `temp`, so the original assignment was pointless and had no lasting effect. You then modify the `malloc`ed memory, but that doesn't change `myArray` at all. To change `myArray` in `main`, you have to assign

```
*myArray = temp;
```

at the end of `FillArray`.

```
void FillArray(int** myArray)
{
     int* temp;
     temp = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
     temp[0] = 1;
     temp[1] = 2;
     *myArray = temp;
}
```

does what you intend.

Comment: @DanielFischer temp actually gets nothing (*myArray) on first line will raise Access Voilation, as myArray is NULL and cannot be dereferenced

Comment: @Abid No, he calls `FillArray(& myArray);`, the fact that `myArray` in `main` has the same name as the function parameter is confusing. In `FillArray`, `*myArray` is `NULL`, what `myArray` in `main` is.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh!! I misread. I though he was passing a ** . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the malloc'd buffer to just a local variable on the stack, and then leaking that memory when you return.  You are never affecting the pointer passed into the function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, you detected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* temp = (*myArray);
```

`temp` is a local variable. What ever modifications made to it will not affect the original.

```
temp = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);  // Will not affect *myArray
```

It's more or less like -

```
void foo( int * ptr )
{
   ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) );
}

int *a ;
foo(a);   // Does `a` get allocated too ? NO.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FillArray(int** myArray)
{
    (*myArray) = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    (*myArray)[0] = 1;
    (*myArray)[1] = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int* myArray = NULL;
    FillArray(& myArray);  
    printf("%d\n", myArray[0]);
    printf("%d\n", myArray[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int* temp = (*myArray);
```

This line is the root cause of the problem, let see what this line.

It says de-reference `myArray` and assign the result value to `temp` which is an `int *`, and since `myArray` is and `int **`, de-referencing would result in a `int *`. But you cannot de-reference a pointer that is not pointing anywhere, since when you passed myArray as the argument it was NULL and when you do (*myArray) it tries to access the memory location pointed to by myArray ( Which is no-where as myArray is NULL) hence Access violation reading location 0x00000000, meaning you are trying to de-reference a NULL pointer.

Apart from the above lets see what your code is doing
The picture in the start is like this

```
myArray ======> NULL
```

after 1st line

```
int* temp = (*myArray); //pointing temp to (*myArray)
```

since myArray is NULL  temp points no where hence the new picture

```
myArray =======> NULL
temp =======> NULL
```

line 2
temp = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

Allocating memory of two integers and pointing temp the newly allocated memory so the picture becomes

```
myArray =======> NULL
temp =======> [ ] [ ]
```

next two line store 1 and 2 on 1st and 2nd memory locations pointed to by temp

```
 temp[0] = 1;
 temp[1] = 2;
```

so now the picture is

```
myArray =======> NULL
temp =======> [1] [2]
```

Answer (score -2):

Malloc temp before you assign!