# Passing array from main and modify it through another function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So my question is that if I have the following code

```
main(){
char arr[1][3];
foo(arr);
}

void foo(char arr1[1][3]){

arr1[0] = "AB\0";
}
```

Does this mean that the value in arr from main would also be modified into "AB\0"?

Comment: You should first search if similar qus asked or not....

Comment: Got it, thank you. Yea, I need to modify my keywords during searching... appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking this stack overflow question and answer, it is an age-old question

[Passing an array by reference in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106957/pass-array-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Why not test it out yourself?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char arr[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char arr[5] = "test";
    printf("%s\n", arr);

    foo(arr);
    printf("%s\n", arr);

    return 0;
}

void foo(char arr[])
{
    arr[0] = 'p';
}
```