# pointers to the array of structures

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the array of pointer to the structure?

is it something like this:

```
StructureName objectname[size];

int *ptr;
ptr=objectname;
```

Please confirm me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *array of pointers to some structure*:

```
StructureName* objectname[size];
//           ^
```

which is the closest thing I can think of when you refer to:

> array of pointer to the structure

Comment: Actually having simply `objectname[size]` makes that a pointer no?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix it doesn't make a pointer. It makes an array. In some circumstances, the array may decay to a pointer.

Comment: array of pointer to the structure is not the one I have mentioned ? I have taken another pointer, is it what is called array of pointers to structure?

Comment: @user3123327 No, you have a single pointer to an array of objects.

Comment: @user3123327, the above is "array of **pointers** to structure", in your question you say "array of **pointer** to structure".

Comment: @user3123327 You mentioned two different things. You should clarify your question.

Comment: and if we want to send it to the function as argument can we write like this functionName(objectname)?

Comment: "... if we want to send it to the function as argument ..." - that's a different question again. Its hard to help you when you do things like that (and the downvotes are frustrating when they answer the question you ask). For this new question, see [Passing an array by reference in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309136/passing-arrays-to-function-in-c) and [Passing Arrays to Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106957/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant `ptr` to be a `StructureName*`, otherwise your code won't compile.

No, that is not an array of pointers to a struct. What you have done is used array-to-pointer to conversion to assign the array `objectname` to `ptr`. This makes `ptr` a pointer to the first element of the array.

An array of pointers to struct is something like:

```
StructureName* objectname[size];
```

Here, we are declaring an array `objectname` that has `size` pointers to `StructureName`s. The elements of the array are pointers. This makes it an array of pointers.

On the other hand, your title asks about a pointer to an array of structs, in which case it would look like this:

```
StructureName (*objectName)[size];
```

Comment: "This makes ptr a pointer to the first element of the array." -- Absolutely not. His code, thanksfully, [won't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/035a38dbeeba29b0).

Comment: @Jeffrey I didn't notice that `ptr` was an `int*`. I'm guessing that's a mistake?

Comment: "your title asks about a pointer to an array of structs" -- His question body says "array of pointer to the structure".

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes, but his title says "pointers to the array of structures", which is why I answered both.