# How to return pointers from CUDA to C without memory allocation?

Tags: c, cuda

I have CUDA function that returns 3 pointers: csrVal, csrRowPtr, csrColInd.

```
void dense2Csr (int dim,
             cuComplex *dnMatr,
             cuComplex *csrVal,
             int *csrRowPtr,
             int *csrColInd)
{
cusparseHandle_t   cusparseH = NULL;   // residual evaluation
cudaStream_t stream = NULL;
cusparseMatDescr_t descrA = NULL; // A is a base-0 general matrix
cusparseStatus_t cudaStat1 = CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS;
int nnZ;

//Input GPU Copy
cuComplex *d_dnMatr;
int *d_nnzRow;


//Output GPU Copy
cuComplex *d_csrVal;
int *d_csrRowPtr;
int *d_csrColInd;


cusparseCreate(&cusparseH); //Create SparseStructure
cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
cusparseSetStream(cusparseH, stream);
cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA);
cusparseSetMatType(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO); //Set First Element RowPtr eq. to zero


cudaMalloc((void **)&d_dnMatr   , sizeof(cuComplex)*dim*dim);
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_nnzRow   , sizeof(int)*dim);
cudaMemcpy(d_dnMatr  , dnMatr   , sizeof(cuComplex)*dim*dim  , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


cusparseCnnz(cusparseH,
             CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW,
             dim,
             dim,
             descrA,
             d_dnMatr,
             dim,
             d_nnzRow,
             &nnZ);




cudaMalloc((void **)&d_csrRowPtr   , sizeof(int)*(dim+1));
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_csrColInd   , sizeof(int)*nnZ);
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_csrVal   , sizeof(cuComplex)*nnZ);


cudaStat1 = cusparseCdense2csr(cusparseH,
                   dim,
                   dim,
                   descrA,
                   d_dnMatr,
                   dim,
                   d_nnzRow,
                   d_csrVal,
                   d_csrRowPtr,
                   d_csrColInd);

assert(cudaStat1 == CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS);

cudaMallocHost((void **)&csrRowPtr   , sizeof(int)*(dim+1));
cudaMallocHost((void **)&csrColInd   , sizeof(int)*nnZ);
cudaMallocHost((void **)&csrVal   , sizeof(cuComplex)*nnZ);

cudaMemcpy(csrVal, d_csrVal, sizeof(cuComplex)*nnZ, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(csrRowPtr, d_csrRowPtr, sizeof(int)*(dim+1), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(csrColInd, d_csrColInd, sizeof(int)*(nnZ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);



if (d_csrVal) cudaFree(d_csrVal);
if (d_csrRowPtr) cudaFree(d_csrRowPtr);
if (d_csrColInd) cudaFree(d_csrColInd);
if (cusparseH  ) cusparseDestroy(cusparseH);
if (stream     ) cudaStreamDestroy(stream);
```

And I call it in C code (with 100% proper linking):

```
dense2Csr(dim, Sigma, csrValSigma, csrRowPtrSigma, csrColIndSigma);
```

or

```
dense2Csr(dim, Sigma, &csrValSigma[0], &csrRowPtrSigma[0], &csrColIndSigma[0]);
```

And in both ways it writes me

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

So, it is a memory error, and I solved it just by allocating a host memory in the main program (and without cudaMallocHost in the function) just before calling dense2Csr. But now I am unable to do it in this way. So, is there a recipe to make the function eat a null poiters, and make it return a pointer to a memory region in a such setup?

Comment: Pass the pointers by reference, not value. Look at how cudaMalloc works.

Comment: Well, the trick is that I'm using C, not C++

Comment: Neither is cudaMalloc. C has a pass by reference idiom. It doesn't have references. What you you do if dim needed to be modified within the function? There in lies the answer for the pointers also

Comment: Well, I would use &dim instead of dim, but as I already wrote, It doesn't work. I don't understand you. What I didn't mention is that dense2Csr function is inside a shared library.

Comment: I will repeat my first comment again. Look at the prototype for cudaMalloc and then ask yourself why that works. That is exactly what you need here

Comment: I do appreciate that you still answering, but still, I'm too dumb to understand either you or cudaMalloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have found the C [pass by reference idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106957/681865) by yourself, and that will work perfectly fine for what you seem to need to do.  A much more elegant and logical way to do the same thing is to define a structure containing the pointers you allocate within your function, and have the function return the structure by value.

So your code could be modified like this:

```
#include <cusparse.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    cuComplex *csrVal;
    int *csrRowPtr;
    int *csrColInd;
} csr_struct;

csr_struct dense2Csr (int dim, cuComplex *dnMatr)
{
    cusparseHandle_t   cusparseH = NULL;   // residual evaluation
    cudaStream_t stream = NULL;
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA = NULL; // A is a base-0 general matrix
    cusparseStatus_t cudaStat1 = CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    int nnZ;

    //Input GPU Copy
    cuComplex *d_dnMatr;
    int *d_nnzRow;

    //Output GPU Copy
    cuComplex *d_csrVal;
    int *d_csrRowPtr;
    int *d_csrColInd;

    // return value
    csr_struct mat;

    cusparseCreate(&cusparseH); //Create SparseStructure
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
    cusparseSetStream(cusparseH, stream);
    cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA);
    cusparseSetMatType(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO); //Set First Element RowPtr eq. to zero

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_dnMatr   , sizeof(cuComplex)*dim*dim);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_nnzRow   , sizeof(int)*dim);
    cudaMemcpy(d_dnMatr  , dnMatr   , sizeof(cuComplex)*dim*dim  , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cusparseCnnz(cusparseH,
            CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW,
            dim, dim, descrA, d_dnMatr, dim,
            d_nnzRow, &nnZ);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_csrRowPtr   , sizeof(int)*(dim+1));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_csrColInd   , sizeof(int)*nnZ);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_csrVal   , sizeof(cuComplex)*nnZ);

    cudaStat1 = cusparseCdense2csr(cusparseH,
            dim, dim, descrA, d_dnMatr, dim, d_nnzRow,
            d_csrVal, d_csrRowPtr, d_csrColInd); 
    assert(cudaStat1 == CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS);

    cudaMallocHost((void **)&mat.csrRowPtr   , sizeof(int)*(dim+1));
    cudaMallocHost((void **)&mat.csrColInd   , sizeof(int)*nnZ);
    cudaMallocHost((void **)&mat.csrVal   , sizeof(cuComplex)*nnZ);

    cudaMemcpy(mat.csrVal, d_csrVal, sizeof(cuComplex)*nnZ, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(mat.csrRowPtr, d_csrRowPtr, sizeof(int)*(dim+1), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(mat.csrColInd, d_csrColInd, sizeof(int)*(nnZ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    if (d_csrVal) cudaFree(d_csrVal);
    if (d_csrRowPtr) cudaFree(d_csrRowPtr);
    if (d_csrColInd) cudaFree(d_csrColInd);
    if (cusparseH  ) cusparseDestroy(cusparseH);
    if (stream     ) cudaStreamDestroy(stream);

    return mat;
}

int main()
{
    const int dim = 1024;
    const size_t sz = sizeof(cuComplex) * dim * dim;
    cuComplex* dmat = malloc(sz);
    memset(dmat, 0, sz);
    const cuComplex ten_plus_nine_i = { 10.0, 9.0 };
    for(int i=0; i<dim; i++)
        dmat[i * (dim + 1)] = ten_plus_nine_i;

    csr_struct smat = dense2Csr(dim, dmat);

    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        cuComplex x = smat.csrVal[j];
        printf("%d %d %f + %f i\n", smat.csrColInd[j], smat.csrRowPtr[j], x.x, x.y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which appears to work correctly (note this example requires a C99 compliant compiler even if the structure return code doesn't):

```
$ nvcc -Xcompiler="-std=c99" -o intialainen intialainen.c -lcudart -lcusparse
cc1plus: warning: command line option -std=c99 is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]

$ ./intialainen 
0 0 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
1 1 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
2 2 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
3 3 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
4 4 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
5 5 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
6 6 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
7 7 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
8 8 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
9 9 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
```

or directly using gcc:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -o intialainen intialainen.c -I /opt/cuda-9.0/include -L /opt/cuda-9.0/lib64 -lcudart -lcusparse -lcuda
$ ./intialainen 
0 0 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
1 1 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
2 2 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
3 3 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
4 4 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
5 5 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
6 6 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
7 7 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
8 8 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
9 9 10.000000 + 9.000000 i
```

The function call `csr_struct smat = dense2Csr(dim, dmat)` is simpler and easier to follow than something like `dense2Csr(dim, dmat, &p1, &p2, &p2)` which would be the alternative, although this is entirely a matter of taste.