# Possible to declare an array in function argument?

Tags: c

Is there some way to pass an array of ints into a function in C, like this:

```
func(int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

or like this?

```
func({1, 2, 3});
```

I am aware of the existence of va_list, but it's not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you understand pointers? I think using these would fit your situation perfectly.

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106957/passing-an-array-by-reference-in-c

Comment: I preferred to get the address of an array then pass it to the function with pointer parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a *compound literal* (defined in C11 [§6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5); also a feature in C99):

```
func((int[]){ 1, 2, 33, 491 });
```

A compound literal looks like a cast followed by a braced initializer for the type specified in the cast.  The scope of the compound literal is to the end of the statement block in which it is introduced, so it will be valid for the entire block in which the call to `func()` is found. Consequently, it is valid for the whole of the call to `func()`. And the compound literal is a modifiable value.

We can validly quibble about the interface to the function not specifying how many values are in the array (so how does `func()` know how big the array is), but that is somewhat tangential to the idea of the compound literal notation.

The function itself is a perfectly ordinary function taking an array argument:

```
extern void func(int arr[]);

void func(int arr[])
{
    …
}
```

Or, of course:

```
extern void func(int *arr);

void func(int *arr)
{
    …
}
```

And (with the major caveat about how the function knows how big the array is), you could write:

```
void calling_func(void)
{
    func((int[]){ 1, 2, 33, 491 });
    int array[] = { 2, 99, 462, -9, -31 };
    func(array);
}
```

Comment: May I suggest some extra spacing in the code snippet? Took me a moment to realize that's not the OP's code.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for - I saw this for the first time on hacker news months ago and have spent the last hour or so trying to figure out what it's called. Thank you!